# Why does the compilation process report "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient"

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors, g++, linker-errors

libmysqlclient has been insalled in "/usr/lib64/" such as:

```
sudo find / -name 'libmysqlclient*'
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so
```

the search path of linker contains "/usr/lib64" such as:

```
ld --verbose | grep SEARCH_DIR
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib");
```

Why does the compile command still report an error?

```
g++ -o server  main.cpp timer/lst_timer.cpp http/http_conn.cpp log/log.cpp CGImysql/sql_connection_pool.cpp webserver.cpp config.cpp -g -lpthread -lmysqlclient
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [server] Error 1
```

I tried the following commands according to the prompts of gpt, but none of them worked.

“changing -lmysqlclient in the compile command to -lmariadb or -lmariadbclient”

Comment: the linux version is CentOS7

Comment: `/usr/lib64` is in the common library search path, but `/usr/lib64/mysql` is not. The linker does *not* search subdirectories. Add `-L/usr/lib64/mysql` to add the path.